# android - recyclerview - get bitmap

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I get the bitmap from a recyclerview?

```
recyclerview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);     
Bitmap bitmap = recyclerview.getDrawingCache();     
recyclerview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);           
Bitmap newBmp = bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(),true);
```

And I'm getting an exception

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't copy a recycled bitmap

Comment: Have you tried doing the copy `before` you set it to disabled? i.e. changing the order of line 3 and line 4 in your snippeet?

Comment: @kha you are right man. If can give you the 50 if you want.

Comment: not really bothered about points to be honest. Glad it helped though.

Comment: if anyone wants the 50 points just have to post the answer Kha.

Comment: That's fine. I'll add it as an answer just in case anyone else has the same problem and finds this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code like this:

```
recyclerview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); 
Bitmap bitmap = recyclerview.getDrawingCache(); 
Bitmap newBmp = bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(),true);
recyclerview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Basically what's happening here is that when you call `setDrawingCacheEnabled(false)`, the underlying Bitmap object that has been created is recycled. If you copy the bitmap before you recycle it, it should work as expected.